# Symfony service injection syntax

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony 2 app implemented by another company and came across the following service definition:

```
service_id:
    class: 'path\to\class'
    calls:
       - [setRequest, ['@?request=']]
```

I know what the question mark in `@?request=` means (if the service does not exist, `setRequest` does not get called), but what does the equal sign at the end of  mean?

Thanks!

Comment: the equal sign can be used to inject values based on expressions too, an example of this use here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html

Comment: @teeyo but not used like this ...

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying it can be used like this, for the your case @prehfeldt aleady answered that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equal sign was used to tell the container to ignore scope violations. `request` is in a special scope and the container throws an exception if you use it in a different scope.

Scopes were deprecated in Sf 2.8 and removed in Sf 3.0. See https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/service_container/scopes.html

Also, as of Symfony 2.4 you should use the `request_stack`: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack